# How can I show values with zero in a Group By query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to get the zero values from my status table associated with the case of one user.

So, I have this query that returns me only one value because, I have only one case associated with one status but I want to receive also the another status with value 0.

So I have the status 'Open' and 'Closed'

And when I make the query I get this:

```
statusName    count
   Open         1
```

But I want to receive this:

```
statusName    count
   Open         1
  Closed        0
```

Query:

```
SELECT db.status.name, COUNT(*) AS status 
FROM db.status 
     LEFT JOIN db.case ON db.case."statusId" = db.status.id 
WHERE db.case."userId" = 1 
GROUP BY db.status.id
```

Comment: Move `where` condition to `join` condition, and you'll get what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `WHERE` criteria to the `ON` of the left join:

```sql
SELECT db.status.name, COUNT(db.case."statusId") AS status
FROM db.status
LEFT JOIN db.case
    ON db.case."statusId" = db.status.id AND
       db.case."userId" = 1
GROUP BY db.status.id;
```

Your previous `WHERE` clause will filter off any record not matching user 1.  The above version retains all records, but just won't count records from the left table that didn't match anything in the right table.